# Integrating phpBB with CAS - casldapauthbb

Tags: authentication, ldap, integration, cas, phpbb3

I'm attempting to integrate phpBB with CAS so that I can utilise the single sign on across a host of websites. So far I have tried a few things but none have pulled off yet. The closest I have come is with the following MOD:

https://sourcesup.cru.fr/projects/casldapauthbb/

However after installing it when I add my CAS details to CAS server name, CAS server port, CAS uri, and leave the LDAP fields blank, I get the error, could not connect to LDAP server.

If anyone knows how to fix this, that would be cool.

I'm also open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this without rewriting large parts of the phpBB framework. So I'm going to run phpBB separately and link accounts through a common library.